# Preload with elixir and phoenix

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm running into this error when I'm trying to create a session with a user from the database. My user schema has_many projects So when I try to create the session I get this error

`projects: #Ecto.Association.NotLoaded<association :projects is not loaded>`

I think I understand what it is saying but I don't know where to preload the data so that the page will render here is the full error that I receive.

```
defmodule PerriAir.Router do
 use PerriAir.Web, :router
 use Honeybadger.Plug
 use ExAdmin.Route    

 pipeline :browser do



protocol Enumerable not implemented for %PerriAir.User{__meta__: #Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:loaded, "users">, id: 8, inserted_at: #Ecto.DateTime<2016-12-23 15:38:38>, password: nil, password_hash: "$2b$12$NxLaK3ZUVPLE23E1L.64GOjm7FtTLemXPUXsp6gSAP346is8e6d5e", projects: #Ecto.Association.NotLoaded<association :projects is not loaded>, updated_at: #Ecto.DateTime<2016-12-23 15:38:38>}
```

I'm new to elixir and phoenix so any help with this error would be appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Where you're fetching `user`, you need to **explicitly** `preload` associated `:projects`, so in controller you have presumably something like:

```
user = Repo.get(User, user_id)
```

This has to be turned to something like:

```
user =
  User
  |> Repo.get(user_id)
  |> Repo.preload(:projects)
```

Please note, the code is formatted and [`pipe operator`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#%7C%3E/2) is used here for clarity. Equivalent of it would be something like:

```
user = Repo.preload(Repo.get(User, user_id), :projects)
```

*I've added that here because you've mentioned you're new to elixir*.

If you want to read more about `Ecto`'s `preload`, take a look here: https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Repo.html#c:preload/3

Hope that helps!